# Django--URL Caching Failing for Class Based Views

Tags: django, caching, view, django-views, django-urls

I've built a RESTful API on top of the Django Rest Framework.  The URL conf for the API is composed of class based views.

I would like to cache these views, however, the following is failing. Any thoughts on why that might be and how I could change it?

```
   from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

   urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^dounces/?$', cache_page(60*60)(DounceListView.as_view(resource=DounceResource)), name='dounces_api'),
```

I have the following middleware installed.

```
'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
```

AND for local testing, i'm using the default caching backend:

```
 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
```

Comment: Failing how? With an error, or just not caching the page?

Comment: No caching.  I added a list of included middleware in case I was missing something there.

Comment: How is it failing? Are you running uwsgi processes? If so, then each process will have its own cached version if your page generate different content on each request.

Answer (score 3):

change your urlconf to

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dounces/?$', cache_page(60*60)(DounceListView.as_view(resource=DounceResource)), name='dounces_api'),
)
```

also see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf

Comment: This answer is out of date. The [Django 1.6 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf) show that the decorator should used as `cache_page(60*60)(MyView.as_view())`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is out of date. The correct way is detailed here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf

It has to now be done this way:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dounces/?$', cache_page(60*60)(DounceListView.as_view(resource=DounceResource)), name='dounces_api'), 
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont see any "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware" and "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware". I dont think it can cache properly without it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask an effective question.