# cache_page with Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to do cache_page with class based views (TemplateView) and i'm not able to. I followed instructions here:

[Django--URL Caching Failing for Class Based Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841772/django-url-caching-failing-for-class-based-views)

as well as here:

https://github.com/msgre/hazard/blob/master/hazard/urls.py

But I get this error:

```
cache_page has a single mandatory positional argument: timeout
```

I read the code for cache_page and it has the following:

```
if len(args) != 1 or callable(args[0]):
    raise TypeError("cache_page has a single mandatory positional argument: timeout")
cache_timeout = args[0]
```

which means it wont allow more than 1 argument. Is there any other way to get cache_page to work?? I have been digging into this for sometime...

It seems like the previous solutions wont work any longer

Comment: If you don't append your urls.py we wont be able to help...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to the [caching docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf), the correct way to cache a CBV in the URLs is:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

url(r'^my_url/?$', cache_page(60*60)(MyView.as_view())),
```

Note that the answer you linked to is out of date. The old way of using the decorator has been removed ([changeset](https://github.com/django/django/commit/bb12a02bd8cd6e33b947b2cfa01292822099bb19#diff-f0e28a990340be56087383c589a99107R186)).

Comment: It doesn't feel right hiding the caching in the `urls.py`, but well.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão in this answer, I was showing the correct way to cache a CBV in the urls, because the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841772/django-url-caching-failing-for-class-based-views) was out of date at that time. You don't have to do the caching in urls.py if you don't want to. You could override the `dispatch` method of your view if you prefer (you might find [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) useful).

Comment: @JorgeLeitão - Great solution, but I agree this does not "feel" right. Any updates on this in 2019 would be appreciated! Any thoughts Alasdair?

Comment: @ScottSkiles you can use `method_decorator` as I suggested before. You don't need to override `dispatch` to use it any more, see [Dayson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597162/113962). You might be able to find or write a mixin that works (I see madjardi has one in their answer), but I haven't used any so don't have any recommendations.

Comment: Re: putting the cache decorator in `urls.py` feels weird, but the reason is provided in the Django docs: `This approach couples your view to the cache system, which is not ideal for several reasons. For instance, you might want to reuse the view functions on another, cache-less site, or you might want to distribute the views to people who might want to use them without being cached.`

Answer (score 35):

You can simply decorate the class itself instead of overriding the dispatch method or using a mixin.

For example

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 5), name='dispatch')
class ListView(ListView):
...
```

Django docs on [decorating a method within a class based view.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

Comment: How do you test and invalidate cache page? I am having issues when testing it manually. It still serves cache from disk even though my redis keys are empty.

Comment: Be careful not to decorate the dispatch() method with cache_page() if using LoginRequiredMixin. If a logged-in user populates the cache, the page will become publicly available.

Answer (score 32):

yet another good example CacheMixin
[from  cyberdelia  github](https://gist.github.com/cyberdelia/1231560)

```
class CacheMixin(object):
    cache_timeout = 60

    def get_cache_timeout(self):
        return self.cache_timeout

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return cache_page(self.get_cache_timeout())(super(CacheMixin, self).dispatch)(*args, **kwargs)
```

usecase:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView


class ArticleView(CacheMixin, DetailView):
    cache_timeout = 90
    template_name = "article_detail.html"
    queryset = Article.objects.articles()
    context_object_name = "article"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Feels much better doing this that wrapping the url in a function

Answer (score 13):

You can add it as a class decorator and even add multiple using a list:

```
@method_decorator([vary_on_cookie, cache_page(900)], name='dispatch')
class SomeClass(View):
   ...
```

Comment: Can we set infinite ttl for cache_page?

Comment: @MasOOd.KamYab there is no such way, but you probably never wanna cache something for longer than 1 year

Comment: I know what you mean, but I wanna cache the response for anytime that model has changed so It must be longer than 1 year

Answer (score 3):

I created this little mixin generator to do the caching in the `views` file, instead of in the URL conf:

```
def CachedView(cache_time=60 * 60):
    """
    Mixing generator for caching class-based views.

    Example usage:

    class MyView(CachedView(60), TemplateView):
        ....

    :param cache_time: time to cache the page, in seconds
    :return: a mixin for caching a view for a particular number of seconds
    """
    class CacheMixin(object):
        @classmethod
        def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
            return cache_page(cache_time)(
                super(CacheMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
            )
    return CacheMixin
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another answer, we found this to be simplest and is specific to template views.

```
class CachedTemplateView(TemplateView):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs): #@NoSelf
        return cache_page(15 * 60)(super(CachedTemplateView, cls).as_view(**initkwargs))
```

Answer (score 3):

Would like to add this:
If you need to use multiple decorators for cache like **vary_on_headers** and **cache_page** together, here is one way I did:

```
class CacheHeaderMixin(object):
    cache_timeout = int(config('CACHE_TIMEOUT', default=300))
    # cache_timeout = 60 * 5

    def get_cache_timeout(self):
       return self.cache_timeout

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return vary_on_headers('Authorization')(cache_page(self.get_cache_timeout())(super(CacheHeaderMixin, self).dispatch))(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way cache is stored and it varies for different Authorization header (JWT). You may use like this for a class based view.

```
class UserListAPIView(CacheHeaderMixin, ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CustomUser.objects.all()
```

Comment: needs some indent formatting. but great answer

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found a good cache solution for class based views and created my own: https://gist.github.com/svetlyak40wt/11126018

It is a mixin for a class. Add it before the main base class and implement method get_cache_params like that:

```
def get_cache_params(self, *args, **kwargs):
   return ('some-prefix-{username}'.format(
       username=self.request.user.username),
            3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variation of the `CachedView()` mixin - I don't want to cache the view if the user is authenticated, because their view of pages will be unique to them (e.g. include their username, log-out link, etc).

```
class CacheMixin(object):
    """
    Add this mixin to a view to cache it.

    Disables caching for logged-in users.
    """
    cache_timeout = 60 * 5 # seconds

    def get_cache_timeout(self):
        return self.cache_timeout

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self.request, 'user') and self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Logged-in, return the page without caching.
            return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # Unauthenticated user; use caching.
            return cache_page(self.get_cache_timeout())(super().dispatch)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Wondering how you got the request.user working in this case -- no matter what I do the CacheMixin will always return an AnonymousUser whileas the underlying (Model)Viewset will in fact return the actual user... What's the magic here?

Comment: @Liam If I do `print(self.request.user)` as the first line in `dispatch()` then I see `AnonymousUser` if I'm not logged in and `phil` (my username) if I'm logged in. Do you see something else, or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: The `print(self.request.user)` keeps printing `AnonymousUser` for me, even when logged in. It feels like dispatch() is called before the authentication happens behind the screens, but then you should have the problem as well.. [Gist for reference](https://gist.github.com/imbue/b5a5cffd212a409bf4a37424b51c7076)

Comment: Strange. I'm using my example code above with a pretty new install of Django that hasn't had much done to it, and if I log in and then view a page, that debug line will print my username. I'm stumped I'm afraid.