# How to enable @cache_page for some of the Django Rest Framework views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cache

I have basic rest framework setup:

```
url(r'^items/$', ItemList.as_view(), name='item-list'),
...
class ItemList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Item
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

I want to cache this request using `@cache_page` decorator. I tried something stupid like:

```
url(r'^items/$', cached_items, name='item-list'),
...
@cache_page(1000)
def cached_items(request):
    return ItemList.as_view()
```

which doesn't work. How can I wrap those views properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21293871/846892

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cache\_page with Class Based Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293543/cache-page-with-class-based-views)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the same decorator you can use in the url patterns with class view as simple view (using `.as_view` method)

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

urlpatterns = ('',
    url(r'^items/$', cache_page(60 * 60)(ItemList.as_view()), name='item-list')
)
```