# How to cache ClassBasedAPIViews in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I am serving list of products in DRF and I tried to use cache in ClassBasedApiViews, 
urls.py

```
path('',ProductListAPIView.as_view(), name='products')
```

views.py:

```
class ProductListAPIView(ListAPIView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

There is no function like `def get() ...` So I can not use conventional decorator before the function to cache.

What I have tried is `path('', cache_page(300)(ProductListAPIView.as_view()), name='products')` this works.

In case of multiple decorators `path('', vary_on_headers('Authorization')(cache_page(300)(ProductListAPIView.as_view())), name='products')` works as well.

Is there a better way to use both decorators `cache_page` and `vary_on_headers` for ClassBasedAPIView?

Comment: Couple of answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293543/cache-page-with-class-based-views)

Comment: Thank you @BrianD I found this one helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26858638/16020090)

Comment: How do you test and invalidate the cache?

Comment: I used postman, there I was able to see the response time, for example first hit takes 80~90ms and the second one takes less than 15ms to serve output. To see if the cache is actually being stored or not you may import cache and check if the keys exists or not using django shell.

Comment: I am currently checking it on Swagger UI , but I am having issues. It seems it is still serving cached data even though my redis keys are empty. I validate that it serves from cached data because from dev tools network tab it shows ("Served from disk cache"). rather than downloading the fresh data

Comment: @RyanAquino Did you configure cache settings for redis cache in settings.py ?  You may follow this : https://tute.io/how-to-cache-django-rest-framework-with-redis

Comment: @Uzzal, yes I also did follow the tutorial you've mentioned. You can better understand my issue I posted it also here in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316195/django-rest-framework-still-respond-with-cached-data-even-after-having-empty-red

Answer (score 1):

You can use method decorator:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator 
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page


@method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 2), name='dispatch') 
class ProductListAPIView(ListAPIView): 
  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 
  queryset = Product.objects.all() 
  serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```