# Django REST framework still respond with cached data even after having empty redis keys

Tags: caching, django-rest-framework, redis

Context: I am facing an issue when caching through redis `ModelViewSet` API view in Django REST framework (DRF) using method decorator `cache_page`.

Docs reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/

Code Snippet: https://hastebin.com/apoqeloyav.py

Example Scenario

Here is the current behavior (tested manually using Swagger UI)

1. send GET request to /products  endpoint  -> this will request to my DRF server and cache the view
2. send GET request to /products  endpoint   again -> this will respond products data as cached data (as verified in dev tools network tab "Served from disk cache"). It also means that it didn't hit my DRF server to retrieve the data.
3. send PATCH request to /products/{product_id} endpoint -> this will update details then invalidate cache (Redis cache keys are now empty at this point)
4. send GET request to /products  endpoint  again -> **This  will still respond product data as cached data (verified because the updated data from doing step 3 is still not present). It also means that it didn't hit my DRF server to retrieve the data.**

[image]

Here is my expected behavior (tested manually using Swagger UI)

1. send GET request to /products  endpoint -> this will request to my DRF server and cache the view
2. send GET request to /products  endpoint   again -> this will respond products data as cached data (as verified in dev tools network tab "Served from disk cache"). It also means that it didn't hit my DRF server to retrieve the data.
3. send PATCH  request to /products/{product_id} endpoint -> this will update details then invalidate cache (Redis cache keys are now empty at this point)
4. send GET request to /products endpoint  again -> **This should respond product data that comes from the database. This means it hits my DRF server to retrieve the updated data.**

**How do I get the expected results so that if redis cache is empty, it should hit my DRF server to retrieve the latest data and cache the succeeding calls until its invalidated again? Also, I am not sure if this is an issue, or just a normal behavior.**

Here is what I tried so far when invalidating the cached data from redis, but none of them works and still serves cached data

1. set cache expiry to 0
2. set cache value to None
3. Delete all keys programmatically
4. Delete all keys via redis-cli
5. Shutdown redis-server -> but still serves `from disk cache` and does not hit my DRF API endpoint

Here are the version sI am using

- djangorestframework==3.11.0
- Django==3.0.8
- redis==3.5.3
- drf-yasg==1.17.1 -> this is the Swagger UI Docs
- django-redis==5.0.0

Answer (score 2):

The request from 4. does not even hit the redis cache, because it returns a local cache (note the "From disk cache" in response code).

You should differentiate between a public cache (i.e. the server cache used by all users) and a private cache (the user's browser cache).

I think, when using `cache_page` decorator, other than caching the request, it also sets "Cache-control" response headers to allow a private cache of the request. The browser uses those headers to cache the request locally, and return a local cached response until `max-age` expires.

To prevent this behaviour, at the server level, you can use `@never_cache` decorator, which sets `Cache-control` response headers to prevent local caching, or use `@cache_control(public=True)` to allow only public cache of the request (this also tweaks the cache control response headers accordingly).

More on [Controlling cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My goal is to cache it only in the redis (public cache). I tried using `cache_control(public=True)` like you said with `cache_page`, but it seems it is still caching it locally even though `Cache-control: public` is in its headers. What approach do you recommend? Do I need to use low level caching for this case ?

Comment: it seems that you need to implicitly set cache control headers `@cache_control(public=True, max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)` or use `@never_cache` which sets all those values.

Comment: I tried both methods you've mentioned but, it did not store any cache on my redis ? and as checked, I am being served a fresh data every request sent

Comment: @RyanAquino From my the docs, `never_cache()` is a view decorator that adds headers to ensure the response won’t be cached by browsers or other caches, that is why redis cache is not working.

Comment: @RyanAquino From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), `no_store=True` means **don't cache**. To have it working, keep the `max_age` and remove `no_store`. In my case I had it working by doing `@cache_control(public=True, no_cache=True)` . From the docs`no-cache` allows caches to store a response but requires them to revalidate it before reuse

Comment: Hi @theTypan, I tried what you suggested. But it seems it's not caching anything now to my Redis server and all request is being served from server